# How to deduct the quantity of duplicate product in a table with the same product number

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I am having a problem of deducting the quantity of a product if the product is duplicated like in the image below:

Products Table Before Order:

[image]

When someone Ordered: OrderDetails Table

[image]

The Updated Product Table:

[image]

as seen below, the customer ordered 3 Quantity of the Product which has a ProductNo of 1, but only 1 Quantity is deducted from the Products table, What should I do?

here is my code:

```
UPDATE Products 
SET Products.Quantity = Products.Quantity - (Select Sum(OrderDetails.Quantity) 
From Products INNER JOIN OrderDetails ON Products.ProductNo = OrderDetails.ProductNo 
WHERE OrderDetails.Status = 'OK') 
From Products INNER JOIN OrderDetails ON Products.ProductNo = OrderDetails.ProductNo
WHERE OrderDetails.Status = 'OK'
```

Comment: Did you try SET Products.Quantity = Products.Quantity - Sum(OrderDetails.Quantity) ?

Comment: yes i did try that and it says: "An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement."

Comment: UPDATE Products 
SET Products.Quantity = Products.Quantity - (Select sum(Quantity) from   Products P, OrderDetails OD P.ProductNo = OD.ProductNo 
WHERE OD.Status = 'OK') ;

Comment: ow it worked but it deduct to all the products on the table

Comment: UPDATE Products SET Products.Quantity = Products.Quantity - (Select sum(Quantity) from Products P, OrderDetails OD P.ProductNo = OD.ProductNo WHERE OD.Status = 'OK' and P.ProductNo = Products.ProductNo ); wonder if this works... else we need to think

Comment: i solved it, thanks for the help here is the code

UPDATE Products 
SET Products.Quantity = Products.Quantity - (Select Sum(OrderDetails.Quantity) 
From Products INNER JOIN OrderDetails ON Products.ProductNo = OrderDetails.ProductNo 
WHERE OrderDetails.Status = 'OK') 
From Products INNER JOIN OrderDetails ON Products.ProductNo = OrderDetails.ProductNo
WHERE OrderDetails.Status = 'OK'

Comment: however there is still a problem because it adds all the quantity even if the product does not belong to the same ProductNo

Comment: Problem is Inner Query n Outer Query is not mapped properly.

Comment: If you can use triggers, it can update whenever you place n order..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this way (not tested, and I'm coming from sql-server background instead of mysql) :

```
UPDATE Products 
SET Products.Quantity = Products.Quantity 
    - (SELECT SUM(OD.Quantity)
        FROM Products p
            INNER JOIN OrderDetails od ON od.ProductNo = p.ProductNo
        WHERE p.ProductNo = Products.ProductNo
            AND OrderDetails.Status = 'OK'
        GROUP BY od.ProductNo
      )
FROM Products 
WHERE OrderDetails.Status = 'OK'
```